# Websocket when closing window/tab - Chrome

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, websocket, dom-events

I just want to confirm that any websocket(s) open on a page and connected to the server with close right away (or eventually?) when a user closed the tab. Since the console for the page is gone when closing the tab, I am not exactly sure how to test this.

The reason I want to confirm this is to figure out whether its possible to trigger a function call on the websocket close event.

Testing this on Chrome only and websockets are connect to my node server on Amazon EC2.

Comment: The socket itself will be closed when the user closes the tab (or navigates to a different page) and the server will see that the TCP connection was torn down.  There is no guarantee that you can execute any code in the browser window before this happens other than the standard "page closing now" page events.

Comment: I guess I will need to find a work around. Right now I'm working with webrtc peerconnections so a client a socket that'll help it locate a remote client to connect to. Trying to debug my implementation has shown something that seems like a bug - which is when a remote peer disconnects (via closing their tab) the other peer involved in the peerconnection did not get the disconnect event. This is getting a bit too specific though so I wanted to make sure it was not something else before digging deeper.

Answer (score 1):

You can trigger the page close event in from your server using the following snippet.

```
var io = require('socket.io')('http');
io.on('connection', function(socket){
  socket.on('disconnect', function(){
    console.log('user disconnected');
  });
});
```

But you cant trigger more that a page closing events with that function.

Comment: Im actually not trying to do anything server side. On the client's side I wanted to make sure their webrtc peerconnection to other client was guaranteed to be closing at the time their socket with the server closes.